# mySQL foreach row run an update

Tags: mysql, sql

- `Progress` table has `progressId`, `lessonId` and `uniqueId`
- `TestResults` table has `progressId`
- `TestResults` table
  now has `lessonId` and `uniqueId`

This SQL statement foreach `progrssId` in `TestResults` will get `lessonId` and `uniqueId` from `Progress`:

```
select progressId,
       (select lessonId from Progress p where p.progressId = TestResults.progressId) as lessonId,
       (select uniqueId from Progress p where p.progressId = TestResults.progressId) as uniqueId
from TestResults
where progressId is not null;
```

Now I want to **update** `lessonId` and `uniqueId` in `TestResults` table foreach associated `progressId`. I need foreach idea. I don't know how to do that in SQL.

Comment: As the answers to the duplicate question show, you can directly insert the results of a select into a table. However, in this particular case, I do not really understand why you would do that, since you can retrieve the associated values through a join.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to insert new rows in the table TestResults? Maybe you want to update the existing rows with the column values from Progress?

Comment: I am trying to remove these old columns

Comment: Yes, Update not insert

Comment: I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you so much

Comment: Edit your question because as it is phrased it is a duplicate of another question.

Comment: I just updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the 2 tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update TestResults t
inner join Progress p on p.progressId = t.progressId
set t.lessonId = p.lessonId,
    t.uniqueId = p.uniqueId
```